# Extracting a link from a js in an html file

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, download

First: I'm new here, pls write your answers foolproof :D

My problem is:
I have got an html file and I want to get a download link out of it. The problem is: The download gets triggered by a javascript (at least I think so)

In the html file the link of the DL-button is just a "#" and I don't have a clue which script is triggered (I don't have any experience in scripting languages, only Java and C#)

The URL to the Site I'm talking about:
http://pleer.com/download/page/7886408m2FP

I would be really greatful if you are able to help me

Greets EcxaByte

Comment: do you just want the link or are you trying do to some scripting (which would required you to be the owner or have some form of access)

Comment: I just want the link to put it in a file (.txt or something)

Comment: just download the file. Downloads screen of IE, firefox and chrome each have an option to copy the download link...

Comment: Yeah, thought of that too but if i right click the DL Button and go to "copy link" it's just the same link with a # at the end... right click -> "Save As" also just saves the html file

Comment: no... point at the file source, then rightclick, copy link or something similar (I'm on a non-english browser). Just tested that on all 3 browsers  and works fine (in windows7 anyway)

Comment: ah just realized that, thanks but I want a solution where i can get this link by the html file of the site, would this be possible too? Thanks for your help man

Comment: that would probably require scripting (see my first comment).

Comment: Okay... Is there any simple way to do this? I'm not very experienced with scripting, I just started messing around with AutoIt but I wouldn't have any idea how to solve this problem...

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way. You are aware of XSS,  CORS, postmessage, and such?

Comment: Not really, well I'm gonna do it the manual way then, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The file is not in the HTML source of the page, so there's not really any way to scrape it from the page using JS.

When you click on the link to download, look at your console's Network tab and you'll see two network requests.

The first request uses the file id that is on the page and calls a path used just for creating a path to the file.

```
<li style="padding: 0; " class="hide" duration="229" file_id="1az1xhtp7q" singer="A Great Big World" song="Say Something (feat. Christina Aguilera)" link="7886408m2FP" rate="320 Kb/s" size="9.524 Mb" source="default">
  <a file_id="1az1xhtp7q" style="float:left" href="#" class="download download-btn">Download</a>
</li>
```

With the `file_id` the page's ajax functionality can generate a url to the file which it then serves your browser.

So, thats a long way to describe how a quick and simple js function will not get you the URL.

Are you trying to scrape this site for MP3 paths? Doing so will cause sites like this to lock people out and require user registrations in future. Might be worth considering.